# reduce oracle ec2 instance

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redhat

We have currently an Oracle12 Standard edition On Redhat with instance m3.medium since five years.
Now final customers want reduce cost.
Could we change ec2 instance from m3.medium to t2.medium or less without risk ?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

It is **not generally a good idea** to run a database on a T2/T3 instance. This is because there are limitations on CPU burst capacity, which can severely impact a database if it becomes too busy for a period of time.

If the database is only being used for Dev/Test purposes, then it okay. However, it wouldn't be a good idea to use T2/T3 for Production usage.

You can change the instance type as follows:

- **Stop** the instance
- Change the instance type
- **Start** the instance

As to risk... If something goes wrong, you can always set it back to `m3.medium` with the same process. If this is a very important system, you should make a backup/snapshot first for safety.